# Font size in putty on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, putty, display-settings

I've upgraded to Windows 7 from Windows XP. Now the font size in putty ist extremely ambiguous: Fonts smaller than 9pt are clear typed unreadable, with 9pt the fonts are too big for my usecase, especially the line breaks.

How can I adjust/optize the font rendering?

Comment: What about the _Terminal_ font with _6pt_ or _9pt_?

Comment: Yes, ``Terminal`` renders quite okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Terminal* font provides decent readability at 6pt or 9pt since it ignores ClearType (raster font). Other examples are *Fixedsys* or *Courier* (but not *Courier New*).

Also, have a look on *Consolas*: This ClearType font is quite readable even at 8pt.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your remote system, you might want to use a font like DejaVu Sans Mono, and also set your encoding to UTF-8. It makes using more customised terminals easier to use (e.g. [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) themes almost all use UTF-8 characters in the prompt)